# Evaluate the sum : $\frac{1}{1+x_{1}}+\frac{1}{1+x_{2}}+\frac{1}{1+x_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{1+x_{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Question :

Let the real  number $x≥1$ :

$x_{1}=x$ and $x_{n+1}=x_{n}(1+x_{n})$ for

$n=1,2,3...$

Then find the sum :

$S=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+x_{k}}$

My try :

Note that : $\frac{1}{1+x_{1}}=\frac{1}{x_{1}}-\frac{1}{x_{2}}$

Also : $\frac{1}{1+x_{k}}=\frac{1}{x_{k}}-\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}$

So if we take sum rights-left  we get :

$S=\frac{1}{x_{1}}-\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}$

I need see other method ?

And it's possible to find the term of $x_{n}$ ?

Comment: Yes this is a correct method.

Comment: You will see your method used in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571140)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac{1}{a_1 + 1} + \frac{1}{a_2 + 1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n + 1} &lt; 2$ for all $n \ge 1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762025/prove-that-frac1a-1-1-frac1a-2-1-dots-frac1a-n-1)